# Bintray API access, user accounts and repository management

Tags: bintray

I've been using Artifactory for a while and it's been a great addition to my CI/CD pipelines.  I have a new use case which I feel might work better with Bintray.

I need to be able to push distribution packages to a cloud/managed repository and do the following:

1. Replicate the packages to multiple private repositories.  Some files will replicate to multiple repos but no package will be deployed to every repo.

   2. Generate an API key only per repo.  I don't need or want full user accounts per repo, I only want to provide download/read access via the REST API.  That is, I do not intend to provide a username and password for  each private repo.
   3. I need to be able to rotate/expire API keys programmatically e.g. on a recurring schedule.

Is there any way to do this with Bintray?  I like the fine grained security model and auditing but I'm not sure it will fit my platform design perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Bintray may be a good solution for your use cases.

1. There is no concept of replication, but you may want to use links: https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_link_package
   It might not be exactly what you need, but may work for you. In general linking will make a reference for a package from one repository to another. You can control the linked files with path prefix.
2. You shall use the access key and entitlements feature in Bintray. An access key is a limited user, which by default has no access to the web UI, and is meant for REST access. With entitlements you have a very granular control on what the user can access, repo/package/path with read/write permission.

https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_entitlements

3. You can set expiry for an access key on creation, delete and create programmatically via the REST API.

https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_create_access_key

For conclusion, you can definetly use Bintray for #2 and #3 as is. For #1 please provide some more data on the use case and I will try finding a solution or use links.

All is available via REST API.

For general information about entitlements please look at: https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/premium/premium_signedurlsentitlements.html#_entitlements_and_access_keys

Comment: gba, thank you for the feedback, at this point my current plan is to use Artifactory as I believe it can fit my use case as well.